# Projectile motion problem with upward acceleration and horizontal velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, projectile

An electron in a cathode-ray tube is traveling horizontally at 2.10×10^9 cm/s when deflection plates give it an upward acceleration of 5.30×10^17 cm/s^2 .

B.) What is its vertical displacement during this time?

My work https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWJkj.jpg

I am asking this because the answer my teacher gave is 2.3cm

Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, y = y_0 + ut + 0.5at^2, where as you have omitted this 0.5

Comment: And secondly you performed a calculator error as well.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = y_0 + ut + 0.5at^2$

Since $y_0$ and $u$ are $0$, we have $y = 0.5~at^2$.

In your calculation $t = 2.95 \times 10^{-9}$, which is correct.

So, $y = 0.5\times5.30×10^{17}\times (2.95 \times 10^{-9})^2$

Therefore,
$y = 2.3~\text{cm}$

Comment: No problem user1530249!